# Carousel that automatically changes image [JS]

Tags: javascript, time, carousel

I'm trying to make a carousel that after 3 seconds changes image.

I got 3 images as `slide1, slide2, slide3`
and thanks to the methods `change1,change2,change3` changes image.

I would like to automate everything like this:

```
function time(change1, change2, change3) {

  this.change1 = change1;
  this.change2 = change2;
  this.change3 = change3;
  t = setInterval(change1 && change2 && change3, 3000); //obviously it doesn't work.

}
/*
---------------ANOTHER METHOD-----------------
*/

function time() {
  t = setInterval(check, 3000);

}

function check() {
  if (slide1.style.display = "inline-block") {
    change2();
  } else if (slide2.style.display = "inline-block") {
    change3();
  } else {
    change1();
  }
}
```

but i don't know how

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well that is an easy job, here is a simple example on how you could do it

I used jq but you will get the idee. if you want only js that let me know will do it to

```js
/// use jq for batter effekt

var sliders = $(".container > div");
var current;
function change() {
  if (!current)
    current = sliders.first();
  else {
    current.hide("fast");
    current = current.next();
  }
  if (current.length == 0)
    current = sliders.first();
  current.show();
}

setInterval(change, 2000);
```

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  border: 1px solid #CCC;
}

.container>div {
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 100px;
}

.container>div:not(:first-child){
 display: none;

   }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">

  <div style="background:red;"></div>

  <div style="background:green"></div>
  <div style="background:blue"></div>


</div>
```